# Python Asyncio StreamReader not cooperating with transport

Tags: python, sockets, server, python-asyncio

I need to update code that relied on asyncio on Server side but no asyncio on the client side, only socket.socket() (and it worked). When I try to update client side to use asyncio StreamReader&StreamWriter, I encounter problems. While writer sends data (it is received on server), reader does not get the server response.

In server code I have 2 classes - Server() and ConnectionHandler(asyncio.Protocol). Server.run() is asyncio entry point (with setting signal handling, periodic check for timeouts etc.):

```
async def run(self):
      self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
      self._loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, self.inthandler)
      self._loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, self.inthandler)
      server = await self._loop.create_server(lambda: ConnectionHandler(self), host=socket.gethostname(), family=socket.AF_INET)
      _save_sock_data(server.sockets(0).getsockname())  # writes ip&port to a helper file
      self._loop.create_task(self.timeout_check())
      async with server:
            logger.debug('Server started!')
            await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(Server.run())
```

ConnectionHandler has methods data_received(self,data), connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.transports.BaseTransport), connection_lost(self), timeout_check(self). Data_received is quite big "if"-tree depending on what it receives and server state, but the logs show it it goes properly... until suddenly the Disconnect with no exception happens (it shows log from connection_lost). No transport.close() is called before it. Logs show the data was received and decoded properly, then the transport was to send reply with self._transport.write(b'0'). Afaik it sends... But the client reader doesn't get it and awaits it forever.

ConnectionHandler snippets:

```
def connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.transports.BaseTransport) -> None:
    self._transport = transport
    self._addr = self._transport.get_extra_info('peername')
    logger.debug('Connected to %s', repr(self._addr))

def data_received(self, data: bytes):
    if ... # other stuff
    elif foo_bar:
        self._next_action_A(argument_received)
        logger.debug('next action A - %s', argument_received)
        self._next_action_B()
        logger.debug('next action B')
        self._next_action_C()
        logger.debug('next action C')
        self._transport.write(b'0')
        logger.debug('Sent reply 0')
    elif foo_not_bar: 
        ... # other stuff with nothing after if block
```

Client side, one of many versions I tried. It is called from terminal with single argument:

```
# (imports) 
async def main(argument):
    # (doing some non-awaitable stuff, including getting value x from the argument)    
    sock = await another_coro(x)  # sock = reader, writer ## it is reached and finishes, but not sure it creates proper r&w
    is_it_ready = await check_ready(sock, argument)
    if is_it_ready:  # further actions, but this 'if' it is never reached

async def another_coro(x):
    ip, port = _get_sock_data()  # takes ip&port from a helper file
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # not used in attempt 1; used in original code
    sock.connect((ip, int(port)))  # not used in attempt 1; used in original code
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(sock=sock)  # not used in attempt 1
    # reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(ip, port)  # attempt 1
    return reader, writer

async def check_ready(sock, argument):
    reader, writer = sock
    logger.debug('writer %s', writer)
    logger.debug('reader %s', reader)
    writer.write(str(argument).encode('utf-8'))
    await writer.drain()
    reply = await reader.read(1).decode('utf-8')
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.debug('After reading await %s', timestamp)  # never reached
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1]))
```

Reader and writer in client logs:

```
writer <StreamWriter transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>> reader=<StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>>>
reader <StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>>
```

Snippet from server logs:

```
[timestamp] [] Connected to <ip>, <port>  # from connection_made
[timestamp+1s] [] (Next action A, received argument value is written)  # from proper if branch in data_received
[timestamp+2s] [] (Next action B)  # from proper if branch in data_received
[timestamp+2s] [] (Next action C)  # from proper if branch in data_received
[timestamp+3s] [] Sent reply 0  # from proper if branch in data_received, after transport.write(b'0')
[timestamp+3s] [] Disconnected from <ip>, <port>  # from connection_lost
```

I don't understand what is the problem with this reader? They have the same transport as writer - and writer works. I would be grateful for wordful explanation what am I missing or getting wrong about the topic.

EDIT. I did manage to not lose the connection when I replaced the line:

```
reply = await reader.read(1).decode('utf-8')
```

with

```
reply = await reader.read(1)
reply = reply.decode('utf-8')
```